# SPSS automatically create interaction variables for Logistic Regression

Tags: variables, effects, interaction, spss

I am using SPSS and have about 300 variables (categorical, scalar and ordinal) to model. I need an Easy / Quick way to create interaction variable composites for Logistic Regression where interactions exist. R does this automatically and creates about 158 composites (variables that have interactions) – there does not appear to be any automated way to create and input interaction variables in SPSS; having to manually input and or test these 158 composites every time I run a new model is going to be A LOT OF WORK!! Any suggestions on a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be repeatedly running this model and need a way to create these synthetic variables, you should most likely create a syntax file that will do it for you. When you use the GUI in SPSS to run a command, SPSS generates the syntax in the output window. You can copy this syntax and use it to create your own script. So, for instance you might write something like this:

```
DO IF (!MISSING Var1).
COMPUTE Var2 = Var1 * dummy1.
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

And sadly, yes you would have to write this block of code 300 times the first go around, but in the future you can simply run it and have all the new variable computed.

Another approach is to name your variables sequentially and use a loop to process them. So assuming that your variables were sequentially named VarA, VarB, & VarC, then you could do a loop like so:

```
VECTOR VectorVar = VarA TO VarC.
LOOP #cnt = 1 to 3 by 1.
   COMPUTE VectorVar(#cnt) = VectorVar * dummy1.
ENDLOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really looking to put in all 158 interaction terms?  I'd be skeptical of that approach.  But if you want to build variables representing all these interaction terms rather than specify them in the model, you can do it with the CREATE DUMMIES extension command available from the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral).

You could also use Python programmability to build the explicit interaction terms in the logistic procedure.

HTH,
Jon Peck